# Connecting to SQL Server with current user

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclient, networkcredentials, defaultnetworkcredentials

I need to build an service that connects to a SQL Server. My idea for authentication was to use the executing user, so I don't have to work manually with changing passwords. 
To connect to the SQL Server I use the *System.Data.SQLClient*, until now I set up a *SQLConnectionStringBuilder* and hardcode the credentials.

I tried to use the given *NetworkCredentials* from the user but could not find a way to use it for the SQL Connection.

Is there any way this could work? If not, how can I securely save the user credentials (e.g. in a file?) to read when running? The application shall run as a headless service every night so I can't use userinput while running.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you trying to connect to SQL Server as the *identity of the windows service account*? or are you trying to connect as the identity of some external user who is connecting through your service via (say) TCP?

Comment: Windows authentication just works - if you add `Trusted Connection` to the connection string, the current account is used to connect. You don't have to pass any credentials. Are you trying to impersonate a *different* account perhaps? Or use a local account to connect to a database on another server?

Comment: `shall run as a headless service every night` that's a scheduled task, not a service. Services are headless by definition anyway. You can create a scheduled task on Windows that will run even if no-one is logged on. This will run the same way as a service, using the configured account to connect to resources.

Comment: Even with Windows authentication, someone has to change the service account's password periodically. You can get rid of that with [managed and virtual service accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/service-accounts) where the OS itself takes care of updating the password. You won't have to modify your application to use them

Comment: We want to set up the application in the task scheduler and set an executing user which also has the rights on the sql server. It could be the sa. 
But how can i build the connection string from the NetworkCredential Object?
If we could set it up on the sql server, would it make it easier?

Comment: *"It could be the sa."* That's a really bad idea. Use a login and user with the appropriate, and smallest, amount of permissions it needs.

Comment: @Larnu i thought so, but wanted to state the possibility, if this way would be easier.